# Racket 'list-ref' implementation half-working

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

This is a problem from a previous assignment I worked on. We're currently programming in Racket with DrRacket and being early in the semester are just finishing a review of natural recursion.

The specific problem was to complete an implementation of `list-ref` by finishing the nested `nth-cdr` within. Here was the code given:

```
(define list-ref
  (lambda (ls n)
   (letrec
      ((nth-cdr
        (lambda (n)
         ;;body of function
    (car (nth-cdr n)))))
```

Pretty straight forward, the instructions were to implement a naturally recursive version of `nth-cdr`. Here's what I ended up with:

```
(define list-ref
  (lambda (ls n)
   (letrec
       ((nth-cdr
        (lambda (n)
          (cond  
            ((zero? n) ls)
            (else (list-ref (cdr ls) (sub1 n)))
            ))))
     (car (nth-cdr n)))))
```

Passing `nth-cdr` any number other than `0` results in a 'contract violation' of `car` in the body of the `letrec`.

```
(list-ref '(1 2 3) 0) ==> '1
(list-ref '(1 2 3) 1) ==> *expected: pair?* *given: 2*
```

Is it a problem with the scope of `ls` within `nth-cdr`? I have no idea why the body of `let-rec` would take the `car` of `nth-cdr n` and complain about the output?

Anyone have the answer to the likely very simple problem?

Comment: You're calling list-ref instead of nth-cdr.

Answer (score 2):

`list-ref` is easy to write as a tail-recursive function:

```
(define (list-ref lst n)
  (if (zero? n)
      (car lst)
      (list-ref (cdr lst) (- n 1))))
```

---

Update: Your solution must follow the template, you say? Here's a hacky way to do it, but unlike Óscar's solution, it does not use `set!`. But it's still ugly:

```
(define list-ref
  (lambda (ls n)
    (letrec
        ((nth-cdr
          (lambda (n)
            (if (number? n)
                (nth-cdr (cons ls n))
                (let ((ls (car n))
                      (n (cdr n)))
                  (if (zero? n)
                      ls
                      (nth-cdr (cons (cdr ls) (- n 1)))))))))
      (car (nth-cdr n)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your helper procedure must advance over both the list and the index, it won't do to just decrement the number. And it should call itself, not the outer procedure! Also, a bit of error checking won't hurt, try this:

```
(define list-ref
  (lambda (ls n)
   (letrec
       ((nth-cdr
        (lambda (ls n)
          (cond
            ((null? ls) #f)
            ((zero? n) (car ls))
            (else (nth-cdr (cdr ls) (sub1 n)))
            ))))
     (nth-cdr ls n))))
```

To be clear, there really isn't  any need for a helper procedure here, to simplify we could do this:

```
(define list-ref
  (lambda (ls n)
    (cond
      ((null? ls) #f)
      ((zero? n) (car ls))
      (else (list-ref (cdr ls) (sub1 n))))))
```

**UPDATE**

Now that you've mentioned in the comments that there are some additional restrictions, I can offer you the following solution - it works, but believe me, it's ugly. We shouldn't have to mutate state for this simple problem, which could be avoided by passing an additional parameter. Anyway, here you go:

```
(define list-ref
  (lambda (ls n)
    (letrec
        ((nth-cdr
          (lambda (n)
            (cond ((null? ls) '(#f))
                  ((zero? n) ls)
                  (else
                   (set! ls (cdr ls))
                   (nth-cdr (sub1 n)))))))
      (car (nth-cdr n)))))
```

Comment: Hehehehe, great minds think alike (re your most recent edit, vs my answer).

Comment: Ok my apologies, correction to the original given code! I forgot to both add `lamba (n)` in the original and also left out the fact that I'm literally restricted to changing/adding code within the `nth-cdr` only. Unfortunately the goal of the course at the moment is to do things the hard way and for this particular problem that means using the exact 'template' provided. Is it even possible to make the function work simply by implementing `nth-crd`?

Comment: @BimmerM3 No, it won't work unless you mutate `ls` in `nth-cdr`. you can keep `ls` instead of `(car ls)` and do it outside `nth-cdr` (actually a common lisp name. Scheme name is `list-tail`) like in your template. Are you sure there isn't two arguments in the helper?

Comment: I've added a version that follows the template but doesn't use `set!`. But it's still ugly, because it exploits Scheme's dynamic typing.... ;-)

Comment: @BimmerM3 so, which version solves best your question?